# How to make Firefox file associations consistent with Ubuntu file associations?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, file-association

This seems to be a pretty commonly Google question, but one for which there are no answers.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/firefox-download-mime-types-378902
http://www.birkit.com/content/kubuntu-linux/internet/firefox/fix-file-associations-in-firefox.html

Being three links amongst the many.

The gist of what I want to accomplish is to have Firefox understand the file associations I download without me having to manually map all of them myself.  Gnome knows the file extensions, so I would have expected that Firefox could just use the already-known file mappings there to open the right stuff (as I presume Chrome does).  But it doesn't.  At least not for me, using Firefox 4, and not by default.  When I click on a downloaded file right now, Firefox always has to ask me what application should be used to open the file.

A handful of Google results tell me that I can reassociate my file extensions by deleting ~/.mozilla/firefox/[profile name]/mimeTypes.rdf, but while deleting that file does in fact result in a new mimeTypes file being generated, the new mimeTypes is just as barren as the old one had been.

Based on the amount of unanswered Qs on the Googlesphere, I know this is a very common problem for Ubuntu users, but it seems to be one for which nobody has chimed in with a good solution.  Maybe Superuser can finally be the panacea for us all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install *ubufox* extension try `sudo apt-get install ubufox`  on a terminal. That transitional dummy package associated file extensions to firefox.
Here's the link https://launchpad.net/ubufox

Comment: Could you add a little more information about what ubufox is and why it would be helpful, possibly with a link to their website? That would make your answer much more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @wbharding so have you solved your problem?

Comment: Didin't work for me on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

As originally stated [here](http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/make-firefox-understand-downloaded-files/):

1. Stop firefox if it is running
2. Delete or rename the mimetypes cache (where firefox keeps its file association settings):

   ```
   $ rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/<yourprofile>/mimeTypes.rdf
   ```
3. Start firefox again
4. Download any file if you had not done this before
5. Open that file from the “Tools > Downloads” menu (by right-clicking on it and selecting “Open“). When asked to choose the application for opening the file, browse to “/usr/bin/xdg-open“. then check the checkbox to “Remember your choice“.